# Microsoft Edge PDF Page Index Cache iframe Issue

Tags: javascript, pdf, microsoft-edge, browser-cache

Background:
Microsoft Edge has a "Pick up where you left off" feature when a user is reading a PDF in the browser. This works well when the user opens a tab directly to the PDF - if the user scrolls to the 15th page, closes the tab, and then opens it again later, Edge automatically takes the user back to the 15th page. This works too if the user opens different PDFs in different tabs - Edge remembers the index for that specific PDF.

The problem is though when those different PDFs are opened within an iframe on a single webpage via Javascript. Opening one PDF, scrolling to page 15, closing that iframe (JS removes that iframe from the DOM), then opening a different PDF in an iframe will open that other PDF to page 15 also, which it shouldn't. We want to maintain a separate cached index for each unique PDF.

It seems that Edge stores PDF index against the URL in the users browser window, not against the URL that appears in the iframe.

I understand this setting can be turned off within the browser, but I'm looking for a developer solution to prevent this from happening for users on the site.

Comment: I'm not certain on this, but as I would expect that functionality to be handled by the PDF renderer within Edge (or whatever browser extension you use to render PDFs) it's highly unlikely that there's going to be a method accessible to external JS which can affect it.

Comment: I would highly recommend opening each PDF in a separate page instead of in the `<iframe>`. If you are in urgent need of PDF rendering in `<iframe>`, you can send a feedback to the Edge PDF Team pressing `Alt+Shift+I`, or give a reply in the [roadmap discussion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/roadmap-for-pdf-reader-in-microsoft-edge/m-p/2175170). But every `<iframe>` in a page requires increased memory and other computing resources. So please avoid using `<iframe>` to render PDFs if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to redirect the iFrame to a page even when resume at last position is active.

I find if you do it manually you need to strike twice for it to be accepted as override so for example If I read to page 2 of 3 then on recall as page 3 it will try to go to page 2 but If I request frame page 3 twice it will then respect that.

So then the URL call needs to be

```
protocol://folder/filename.pdf#page=[number]
protocol://folder/filename.pdf#page=[number]
```

However in standalone test call I only needed to call once externally as fresh tab but then twice is no big issue anyway

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "file:///C:/Users/WDAGUtilityAccount/AppData/Local/Temp/MicrosoftEdgeDownloads/whatever.firefox.pdf#page=3"
```