# How to link to a page in a PDF document without opening a second instance

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I know how to link to a specific page of a PDF document within HTML.  I would like to find a way to do that  repeatedly, without opening a new instance of Acrobat each time.

In other words, for the first link, open Acrobat directly to specific page.   When second link is clicked in HTML page, go to the specific page in the PDF file within the currently opened PDF file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers are the same and some will NOT use Adobe external directives. Those that do such as Chromium based or some Mozilla based will accept OPEN at `#page=` Here I have 2 scripted buttons for the frame (does not have to be scripted but was me testing) that button 1  opens page 1 and button 2 reloads any file with OPEN at page 2.

[image]

Acrobat PDF viewers in HTML use a URL fragment (#) to open a Page as seen here.

[image]

One problem is if the Browser is set to reopen "ALWAYS reopen at last page" then recalling again will only repeat the same page. However if you ask a user to switch that function off. Then you can let them open a different page in the same window.

[image]

The problems in controlling PDF document or user settings are more than that.

The document may be set to only open at an internally defined page number and the "Fragment" can not work. Here I have set the downloaded copy to ONLY open at Page 1 and no mater how many times or ways I call the file Acrobat will only open with Page 1 visible (never starting nor showing page 2 via external command.)

[image]

Same with the scripted version the second call is NOT opening page 2.

[image]

There is also another problem with Chromium based browsers that is not present in Mozilla browsers and that is a reluctance to reuse the same base URL irrespective of page number called and thus this also needs to be allowed for. It was a question I raised myself and the working answer is here [What can I do to change this Edge PDF frame behaviour without JavaScript (Firefox works OK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607378/what-can-i-do-to-change-this-edge-pdf-frame-behaviour-without-javascript-firefo)

**NOTE:-** these behaviours above are from HTML in a browser. However outside a browser it is possible to drive PDF readers directly with the same instance, so that they can scroll or jump pages. The limitations above are because there is no internal access to the PDF Application Programmable Interface only external calls to the framed HTML OPEN embedded framed objects method.